# Click commandline help formatting across multiple lines

Tags: python, python-click

I am using a library called [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/) for making command line apps and to define the description the code looks like this

```
def cli:
    """ Description goes here """
```

So all's well and good until I try to have multiple lines.

Naturally I tried this

```
def cli:
     """ hi
         hi
         hi"""
```

But this doesnt end well. The text gets pushed all over the place and doest look good. I tried adding \n after each line but it just added to big a space where the output ended up looking like this:

```
Output:
       hi

       hi

       hi
```

This reason this can't happen is I have ascii art that needs the lines to be close together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your second attempt is that the line starts from the first `"""` and then includes all text (including whitespace) until the next `"""`. So, when you do this:

```
def cli:
     """ hi
         hi
         hi"""
```

You have 1 space before the first 'hi' and then 9 spaces before the next one. The solution is to either drop the first line down one line, or just remove 8 spaces before the other lines. This should have consistent indentation for each 'hi' when it gets printed:

```
def cli:
    return """
         \b 
         hi
         hi
         hi"""
```

EDIT: Apparently click reformats text before it prints it, but according to [the docs](http://click.pocoo.org/5/documentation/#preventing-rewrapping) adding `\b` should disable that behaviour.

Comment: `click` re-wraps text however, see [the relevant documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/documentation/#preventing-rewrapping).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh. Wow. That is certainly something.